# How to parse an url to trig click function with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, parsing, tabs

For example, when url in a browser adress bar is [`http://fiddle.jshell.net/ynts/s5S6U/show/light/#header2-tab3-p2`](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ynts/s5S6U/show/light/#header2-tab3-p2), these actions should happen:

1. click on `a href="#header2"` element
2. click on `a href="#tab3"` element
3. click on `a href="#p2"` element

---

***For a what I need this?***

My [previuos question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485337/how-to-modify-jquery-tabs-script-to-work-with-nested-tabs) was closed as a clone. However, I still need help with this nested tabs issue. I think that I found a way to resolve this problem with a trick with url parsing.

I have this code:

```
<ul class='headers'>
    <li><a href='#header1'>→ header 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#header2'>→ header 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#header3'>→ header 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id='header1'>
    Hi, this is header1.<hr>
</div>
<div id='header2'>
    This is the header2.<hr>
    <ul class='tabs'>
        <li><a href='#tab1'>header2 → tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tab2'>header2 → tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tab3'>header2 → tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id='tab1'>
        This is tab1.<hr>
    </div>
    <div id='tab2'>
        This is tab2.<hr>
    </div>
    <div id='tab3'>
        This is tab3.<hr>
        <ul class='ps'>
            <li><a href='#p1'>header2 → tab2 → p1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#p2'>header2 → tab2 → p2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id='p1'>
            This is p1.<hr>
        </div>
        <div id='p2'>
            This is p2.<hr>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='header3'>
    And this is header3.<hr>
</div>

<div class="helpers">
    <p id="header1-tab1"></p>
    <p id="header1-tab2"></p>
    <p id="header1-tab3"></p>    
    <p id="header2-tab3-p1"></p>
    <p id="header2-tab3-p2"></p>
</div>
```

---

```
$.fn.myTabs = function() {

    return this.each(function() {

        // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
        // which tab is active and it's associated content
        var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

        // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
        // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
        $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
        $active.parent('li').addClass('active');
        $content = $($active.attr('href'));


        // Hide the remaining content
        $links.not($active).each(function () {
                $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
        });

        // Bind the click event handler
        $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
                // Make the old tab inactive.
                $active.parent('li').removeClass('active');
                $content.hide();


                // Update the variables with the new link and content
                $active = $(this);
                $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

                // Make the tab active.
                $active.parent('li').addClass('active');
                $content.show();


                // Prevent the anchor's default click action
                e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

};


$('.headers, .tabs, .ps').myTabs();
​
```

---

**A jsfiddle with this code and some styling: [jsfiddle.net/ynts/s5S6U](http://jsfiddle.net/ynts/s5S6U/).**

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
<a class="blah" href="/#header2-tab3-p2">Click me</a>
```

...do:

```
$('a.blah').click(function(){
    // Grab href, shave first two chars off, split on "-", operate on each
    var hrefs = $(this).attr('href').substr(2).split('-');
    $(hrefs).each(function(){
        $('a[href="#' + $(this) + '"]').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

That should work

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to implement your code. However, I need the scrit to work with links outside the page. It should work when 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/ynts/s5S6U/show/light/#header2-tab3-p2' is put in a browser adress bar.